# Стыковка объектов на сцене в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

возникла проблема по которой я не могу никак найти решений. Есть ли какие-то способы стыковать кабель-канал друг с другом, даже если человек чуть чуть не довел его до нужной позиции?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данный момент нет никакой автоматической стыковки, и человеку приходится долго вручную прицеливаться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сама система установки взята отсюда: https://null-code.ru/solution/66-stroitelstvo-bazy-rasstanovka-obektov-rts.html

Comment: Может добавить на угол детали обработчик, который ищет другую деталь и если можно поставить, то у первой детали значение `у` равно второй?

Comment: А как понять обработчик? не совсем понял

Comment: Какой нибудь объект, на котором есть тригер, который проверяет деталь вашу

Comment: Надо будет проверить

Answer (score 1):

Если это происходит в редакторе во время редактирования сцены, то можно использовать привязку по вертексам. Двигаешь объект, удерживая ctrl+v или cmd+v(если mac). Тогда unity будет пытаться с минимальным расстоянием прилепить двигаемый объект, ближайший его вертекс, к ближайшему вертексу соседнего объекта.

Comment: Это мне нужно не в редакторе. А чтоб сам игрок расставлял этот кабель-канал

Comment: Самое простое было бы двигать объекты по координатам, кратно какому-то значению. Например, 1 юнит, ну или какой сам задашь. Тогда получится что-то подобное привязке к сетке, как в Photoshop, например. Ну, или можно конечно запариться и написать скрипт, с которым ты бы смог выделить вертекс, к которому хочешь привязаться и вертекс, который хочешь привязать. И далее расчитать на сколько надо сдвинуть привязываемую модель. `Mesh _mesh = meshFilter.mesh; откуда возьмёшь _mesh.vertices` Далее пускать луч в курсор и находить ближайший вертекс. Сам не пробовал. Но в теории должно сработать.

Comment: Если будешь двигать кратно , по-сетке, то главное, чтобы начальные координаты тоже были кратными.. Иначе, не состыкуется.